# Windows 7 Ent login loop

Tags: authentication, windows-7-x64

I have a Windows 7 Ent - 64bit system.

I am stuck in a loop, where the login screen is presented, i enter my network credentials, the welcome spinner is shown, the screen flickers like when resized, then the system goes to logging off screen and then finally goes back to the control alt delete screen.

I cannot get out of that loop for the life of me.

I contacted corp support, he came over and logged in using his login (admin level) and was able to get a desktop up.

The support people are not allowed to access the registry to correct or even look at my users settings, and my user IS NOT AN ADMIN on this machine.

Question is - is there a way to blow away my profile on this machine, or reset my registry branch to that of a new user or something???

i have bitlocker enabled on the drive - so using the emergency boot disks are almost rendered useless...

im stuck, and i dont know where to look....

any ideas would be wonderful

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the admin level user logged in, and turned his back for a moment, and i was able to go in and reset the autologon registry entry...

rebooted,and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect Your USB Devices
If you like using all sorts of USB devices such as the mouse, keyboard, speakers, Bluetooth speakers, USB dongles, USB Wi-Fi adapters etc. However, these connected devices might cause the Windows 7 stuck on the welcome screen for a long time issue. Therefore, a common solution to the problem is to disconnect all externally connected devices from your PC.

Disconnect from the Internet
Sometimes Windows 10 gets stuck on the login screen because it's trying to connect to your wireless connection. If your Windows gets stuck on the welcome screen, you should make sure that you are not connected to the internet before proceeding to log in.

Run system checks
In some case, corrupt system files on your computer will cause this problem – stuck on welcome screen Windows 10/8/7. Therefore, to fix the Windows 10 freezes on startup problem, you can use CHKDSK to run some checks on your computer to see if it is the corrupted files that cause your startup problem.Restart Windows Update service
You can try restarting Windows Update service and then rename few files if you still get stuck on welcome screen Windows 10 issue.

```
Here are the steps:
Step 1. Open command prompt. 
Step 2. Type net stop wuauserv in the run dialogue and press Enter.
Step 3. Type cd %systemroot% command and press Enter.
Step 4. Type ren SoftwareDistribution SD.old and press Enter.
Step 5. Type net start wuauserv and press Enter.
Step 6. Type exit and press Enter to close Command Prompt and restart your PC. 
Step 7. Now, reboot your PC/laptop and check if the stuck on welcome screen has gone.
```

Restore Windows by using System Restore
System Restore is a useful feature that allows you to restore your operating system to a previous state and fixes any boot problems such as Windows 10 freezes on startup, Windows 7 hangs on welcome screen, etc.